# Does Pollard rho works for Gaussian integers?

Tags: algorithms, factoring, gaussian-integers

Should I expect that the [Pollard rho method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm#Algorithm)

```
1. x ← 2; y ← 2; d ← 1;
2. While d = 1: 
  1. x ← g(x)
  2. y ← g(g(y))
  3. d ← gcd(|x - y|, n)
3. If d = n, return failure.
4. Else, return d.
```

will work for Gaussian integers? With a minor change due to gcd?

In my blog [Forth & math](http://forthmath.blogspot.se/) I use the method for single cell numbers and in works fine for 64-bit numbers. For integers I use the function $\;x^2+1$ and a complete factorization is delivered immediatly. Now I will try to define an adequate routine for Gaussian integers and I guess that the method reasonably often will deliver some non trivial factors, but how long would the cycles be before they repeat them selves? Do anyone know if this has been tried?

---

I have now implemented Pollard rho for Gaussian intergers on my blog and it seems to work fine.

However, $g(z)=z^2+1$ doesn't work for all Gaussian numbers, i.e. not for 
$4+3i$ but the function $g(z)=z^2-1$ is well tested and works. See my answer on stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269810/whats-a-nice-method-to-factor-gaussian-integers

Comment: I take it $n$ is the number you are trying to factor, and $g$ is some polynomial. Well, if it gets to step 4, then it works, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, but the method is probablistic and if it success, how efficient would it be compared with brutal force?

Comment: I guess the $\$64$ question is, what's function $g$?

Comment: @hardmath, so you think there might be a function that find useful cycles in a reasonable time?

Comment: I took the focus to be on whether a variant of Pollard's rho can be as effective in finding factors of Gaussian integers as $g(x) = x^2 \pm 1 \bmod{n}$ is for typical rational integers.   Specifically what should be expected for rational integer primes that factor over the Gaussian integers?  A different choice of $g(x)$ would be called for.

Comment: See [Attacking ElGamal based cryptographic algorithms using Pollard's rho algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262221360_Attacking_ElGamal_based_cryptographic_algorithms_using_Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), a 2005 conference paper by Haraty, Otrok, and El-Kassar, in which versions of Pollard's rho *for discrete logarithms* are proposed for both the Gaussian integers and for polynomials over a finite field.  Similar changes to Pollard's rho for *factorization* may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

> but how long would the cycles be before they repeat them selves?

Just with $\varrho$ over $\Bbb Z$, this depends on 
the (size of) the smallest prime factor.  If the number has only (relatively) large factors, then you need many cycles. To give it a try, find the factorization of
$$ 8529706411569586340464 + 101805471873703921229955\, i$$
Nothing special, just 2 prime factors that are not small.

> will work for Gaussian integers?

What's the point? Would factorizing $z$ directly over $\Bbb Z[i]$ be better than factorizing $|z|^2=z\bar z$ over $\Bbb Z$?  When you are computing $\gcd_{\Bbb Z[i]}$ you'll have divide $w$'s that are the size of about $z$; and to do that you'll extend with $\bar w$ and arrive at doing arithmetic with numbers of size $|z|^2$, just like when computing $\gcd_{\Bbb Z}$.

The advantage of factorizing over $\Bbb Z$ is that you can use all the nice factorization algorithms that already exists / are already implemented like [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) that's also very good at finding "small" factors.